# How to change microphone to use in PulseAudio

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

#### Looking to accomplish the following:

- Change default microphone from analog mic to logitech 920C Webcam Mic (or back the other way) from the command line.

  - would like to be able to do this using either/or/both the vendor ID, product id rather than the ugly long complicated device name. My scripting skills are rudimentary so this is lost on me.
- If that does not work, reset the USB connection to the camera so that it is rediscovered.

#### Background

I have a kiosk system that boots fresh every time and is configured from a config file on a web server. Currently I have two microphones connected to the kiosk; an analog mic into the microphone port and a logitech 920C with internal mic. Generally the internal mic comes up as the default. I can pass in commands from the config file and I would like the ability to choose which microphone is active after boot using this method. the system recognizes both microphones but the logitech does not seem to pass any sound into the system even after manipulating it in pavucontrol. The only way I've been able to make it work after a fresh boot is to disconnect it physically and reconnect it, at which point it functions as expected.

#### What I've tried

I've tried a number of methods to try and change the default microphone from analog to the logitech. The below code has worked in changing the default device but it made no change in the function of the microphone.

```
$ pacmd "set-default-source device-name-of-logitech"
```

I can mute and unmute and change volume of the source with the below code but it has no effect on function

```
$ pactl set-source-mute 0 1
$ pactl set-source-volume 0 50%
```

I've also tried to reset the usb device using the below code. When doing so the logitech will dissapear from pavucontrol and then reappear but still without any functional results to make the microphone send audio

```
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4.6/authorized"
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4.6/authorized"
```

It seems like the only thing that works successfully and repeatedly is to physically disconnect/reconnect the camera from the computer. It's a bit of a hack but if I could reproduce that action from the command line I may be able to get it to work, though not very elegantly.

Also, it would be great to be able to send these commands by referencing the vendorID and productID as I'm not always certain of what index the devices will have if the physical connections are slightly different from system to system. As mentioned before my command line scripting skills are pitiful so any help in doing this would be appreciated.

Any help frankly is appreciated...thanks in advance.